# How can I get data from "Analytics" area?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm using the Dialogflow API to manage my bot. At moment, I need to get the the data from "Analytics" area ([dialogflow analytics image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd8an.png)) via node.js. Has some way that I could do this?

I've search a lot how to do this using this lib, but I didn't find nothing.

Has anyone can help me with this?